# Using nested iteration and models with ModelBuilder

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, modelbuilder

I'm new to using ModelBuilder and have to do a nested iteration (for every month I have to iterate through 6 parameters). I am thinking of doing that by using nested models. One model doing the interation through monthes and then providing the current month as parameter to the submodel that iterates through the 6 parameters.

The linking of the models does not work correctly (boxes are not colored).

How can I make the current month value available to the submodel?

I just want the month parameter to be available in a function; I don't connect it to a function as input variable.

Comment: If you provide a screenshot/graphic of the model-in-progress, you will likely receive more specific advice.

Comment: I have had some success working with nested models and iterators. If you provide some graphics that would greatly help understanding your question.

Answer (score 6):

You have to make it ModelParameter see pics.

And then you can add this variable in first model.

[image]

[image]